# How to fix water leaking past toilet bolt?

Tags: toilet

I've recently applied yoga mat as an interior barrier for my toilet tank that has a lot of condensation issues. I used silicon adhesive to prevent the separation between the yoga mat and the tank's walls.

[image]

However, I've noticed after turning the water back on that water is dripping from a bolt.

[image: Water leaking from toilet tank bolt on the left side of the tank]

I've tried to tighten the bolt and it slowed the drip rate to nearly no drips, but I'm finding a small puddle forming at the foot on my toilet tank on the left side regardless.

I placed a small plastic container to catch the drips, but I noticed the container isn't getting filled and a puddle of water was forming beneath it.

Does anyone know why this happening and how I can remedy this problem? My guess is that it is caused by condensation from the tank since the my yoga mat cutouts aren't perfect, but the weird thing is the right side of the tank isn't having this problem.

Comment: What kind of condensation problems are you having?

Comment: Before laying the yoga mat, whenever the toilet tank fills or when someone takes a shower, the entire toilet tank will condense so much that puddles of water would form on the floor over the course of a few hours on both sides of the toilet tank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the rubber washer seals on the bolts. Over time these washers disintegrate and water in the tanks leaks around the bolts.

Comment: I don't know why ordinary rubber is used for these washer seals; other sealing materials (e.g., Teflon, silicone. . . ) would last indefinitely. Note that the bolts have a wide head, flat on the underside. One does *not* use a metal washer between the seal and the head or between the seal and the tank. This would negate the sealing by the soft washer. A metal washer can be and should be used on the underside (outside) of the tank.

Comment: These bolts may have become corroded over time or have deposits on them which interfere with sealing or prevent smooth tightening. They are usually (always?) made of brass so they could possibly be cleaned and reused, but it might be better to replace them. **Don't over-tighten** them; you could crack the ceramic tank.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I saw that a lot of my toilet's internal parts were worn out as well so I replaced the bolts, washers, gasket, flush valve, and flush valve gasket. However, I'm still having a similar leak on the left side of the toilet. I've made sure the toilet bowl is centred and up right. It's not dripping by the bolt anymore, but next to it. When I traced where the water was coming from, it came from the toilet tank where the bolt and gasket was covering.  Are there any other reasons this type of leak can occur?

Comment: Just want to provide an update to the situation. I tried to tighten the bolt once more and found that there was still a fair a bit of room left to tighten; I was overly cautious due to fears of over tightening the ceramic tank. After another round of tightening the bolt until I felt it cannot be tightened any further, the toilet no longer leaks. Thanks to everyone who contributed to this question.